# Is cx_Oracle 5.3 compatible with Oracle client 19.10?

Tags: linux, cx-oracle, oracle19c

We upgraded our Oracle DB and oracle client from 12.1 to 19.10.
Our application server have below setup

- OS is Linux
- Python version is 2.7.5 and there is no plan to upgrade the python version yet
- cx_Oracle library version is 5.3

A quick test shows the application works fine but I am wondering if I need to upgrade the cx_Oracle library? Does it have a support expiry date? I tried to google it, read the information on its Github page but can't find any statement that answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

This combination hasn't been tested. But since the Oracle Client libraries keep compatibility it is likely to work, subject to whatever underlaying enforced changes have been made to the Oracle libraries, perhaps to drop unsupported TLS versions or whatever has occurred in the 8 years since 12.1 was released that I don't know about.  You application testing should be the final confirmation.

You should definitely set a goal to update to Python 3 so you can get the latest cx_Oracle version.